# If I use ng-show to hide columns in a large grid will that improve performance?

Tags: angularjs

I have a large data grid with 20 columns and about 1,000 rows.  The grid displays slowly and seems jerky to move with the scrollbar.

There are 5-6 columns that most of the time I don't need to see.  If I used ng-show to hide those columns from view would that be likely to improve performance. Alternatively are there any other suggestions that might help me with this problem?  I'm using v1.5.0 and the very latest browsers.  Would upgrading to a more recent version help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- ng-show renders the html, just that it hides that; so not gonna improve any performance. ng-if will not render the html; so use ng-if instead.
- I would suggest server side pagination/lazy loading/infinite scroll as 1000 rows will not be readable.
- While rendering if you dont need two way binding use one-time binding {{::}} syntax

Comment: so just replacing ng-show with ng-if should be a quick fix for performance. Is that correct?

Comment: It would, but major improvement would be removing two way binding. Do you need two way binding or just rendering is fine?

Comment: I need two way binding for some of the rows.  I know the {{ }} syntax but what's the significance of the two :: ?

Comment: That would be one-way..framework wont listen or track the changes for those items.

Comment: From angular docs - An expression that starts with :: is considered a one-time expression. One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable, which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a non-undefined value

Answer (score 0):

replacing ng-show by ng-if will make huge improvement for performance. then using one time binding. also try to not use function in huge ng-repeat data. for example ng-class="user.getClass(item)". and less filters.
plus infinite load help you or even better using paginator.
plus turning off debugInfo

```
app.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
}]);
```